# Run multiple web forms apps in same solution in visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms

I have two web forms applications in one solution in Visual Studio 2012. At work, it creates both, but runs only the startup project in debug mode. I can also pull up the second application at the same time. However, in the same solution with the same copy of Visual Studio, my home computer only opens one of them at a time (Only the one you select as the startup project).

How can I get visual studio to run both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-click your solution, and select Properties.  On the left side, navigate to Common Properties -> Startup Project.

Now you can select "Multiple startup projects" and specify which projects will start (with or without debug) when you run the solution.

Comment: Thanks! One more question if you don't mind - when I stop debugging, I can no longer access the website. Is there a setting to keep the website running even when you aren't debugging?

Comment: I'm not sure about that.  I haven't done much work with web projects.

Answer (score 2):

In the solution explorer, right-click on the solution, and choose "Set Startup Projects".

[image]